# AWS lambda enrich / modify input object

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, integration-patterns

Usually you need to do something with [InputPath, ResultPath and OutputPath](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-example.html) to process your data.
But sometimes you need something as simple as modifying a property in your input object, like [camel do](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.18.x/eips/enterprise-integration-patterns.html) with [Message EIP](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/Message.html) or [Enricher EIP](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/DataEnricher.html)
Is there an option to eliminate the configuration overhead?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the approach with [Jackson tree model](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-node-tree-model):

```
public class MyHandler extends JsonHandler<ObjectNode> {

    @Override
    public ObjectNode handleRequest(ObjectNode json, Context context) {
        // enrich or modify the input
        json.putPOJO("enriched", pojo);
        // return (the same) modified input object
        return json;
        // or replace it with something totally different
        // return "Some other POJO";
    }
}
```

Where JsonHandler parent class is defined as

```
public abstract class JsonHandler<R> implements RequestStreamHandler, RequestHandler<ObjectNode, R> {
    
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public void handleRequest(InputStream input, OutputStream output, Context context) throws IOException {
        ObjectNode json = (ObjectNode) objectMapper.readTree(input);
        R result = handleRequest(json, context);
        output.write(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(result).getBytes());
    }

    @Override
    public abstract R handleRequest(ObjectNode json, Context context);
}
```